# If statement in appscript for a range of data

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this code where the first big part is a column rearrangement and the second one contains an 'IF' statement

```
function moveCols() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var fonteEng100 = ss.getSheetByName('Relatório ENG 100 - base');
ss.insertSheet('ENG 100');
var novoEng100 = ss.getSheetByName('ENG 100');
fonteEng100.getRange('A:A').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('A1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('J:J').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('B1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('B:B').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('C1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('C:C').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('D1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('D:D').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('E1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('F:F').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('F1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('E:E').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('G1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('G:G').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('H1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('H:H').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('I1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('K:K').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('J1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('M:M').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('K1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('O:O').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('L1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('P:P').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('M1'));
fonteEng100.getRange('N:N').copyTo(novoEng100.getRange('N1'));

novoEng100.getRange('O1').setValue("SITUAÇÃO");
novoEng100.getRange('P1').setValue("DIAS CORRIDOS");

var situ = novoEng100.getRange('O2:O');
//var dias = novoEng100.getRange('P2:P')

var status = novoEng100.getRange('B2:B');
if(status == "Cancelado"){
  situ.setValues("OS CANCELADA");
}
```

The catch is with the 'IF' statement. I want it to look through all cells in the range 'B2:B' and whenever the cell value in 'B2:B' ="Cancelado" it must return "OS CANCELADA" in the destiny range of 'O2:O'.

How can i make it look through each cell return th expected value (string)?

Comment: I just wanted to add, that getValue(), setValue() is for one cell, but getValues(), setValues() is for multiple cells, and it returns and takes two dimensional array as parameter.

more you can read here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
var situ = novoEng100.getRange('O2:O'+ novoEng100.getLastRow()).getValues();
var status = novoEng100.getRange('B2:B' + novoEng100.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
status.forEach((e,i) => {
  if(e == "Cancelado") {
    situ[i][0] = "OS CANCELADA"
  }
})
novoEng100.getRange(2,15,situ.length, 1).setValues(situ)
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it worked just fine, thank you so much.

Let's say i wanted to add an 'or' statement, like e == "Cancelado" or e == "anything"

i'd need to add it below the 'if' statement like, right?

Comment: Try e == "anything" || e == "something else"

Comment: Right man, thanks. One last thing, it's already solved, but can you please explain me those three lines of code? They would be the 'var situ' one, 'var status' and the last one

Comment: getLastRow() is the method of Class Sheet.  Go look it up in the documentation.